# Calling a method of a super class through extended class leads into TypeError

Tags: coffeescript

I'm not sure if the title says it all.

What I'm trying to do is to have a super class (or a more or less abstract class) which then is used by another class which is extending itself from the super class.

Now what I did was to create a simple script:

```
class Animal
  constructor: (@name, @sound) ->
  setSound: (@sound) ->
  sound: ->
    alert "#{@sound}!!!"

  name: ->
    alert "#{@name}"

class Dog extends Animal
  constructor: (@name) ->
    @setSound "Woof"

doggy = new Dog "Max"
doggy.sound()
```

As you can see - this is just a crappy example but what happens is, when I now call `doggy.sound()` I get an TypeError in return.

You can see this script in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/zrVZb/1/
Am I doing something wrong or is this even a bug in coffeescript?

**edit:** I just saw, that it is `contructor` and not `construct`. But now I'm getting the TypeError instead.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method is called `sound`. But then you pass an attribute with the same name, which overwrites this method. Try renaming your sound method into makeSound :

http://jsfiddle.net/V7Dx8/1/